# Change Iframe Content from Cached HTML?

Tags: c#, javascript, iframe

Is there any way that I can change the content of iframe from a cached html string? I am not talking about iframe.Attribute["src"] = "url", but rather given a string of html and change the content.

An ugly workaround might be saving the html into a file and change iframe src to it. Any other ways? Maybe javascript can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can control the contents of the iframe html, you could do something like this:

Expose a method as such:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function setData(str)
{
$('html').html(str);
}
</script>
```

and call it like

```
document.iFrameName.setData(myHtmlStr);
```

from the parent frame.

Comment: I'm using C#, how to I get a C# string passed to javascript setData(str)?

Answer (score 0):

Stefan Kendall's solution is a good one. As a fallback, if you can't or don't want to use jQuery, you can also `document.write` into the iframe. [Here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1021687)'s an example which I believe will eliminate all the cross-browser quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind this must be on the same domain, otherwise you're into rpc territory...